# Can a Rails app and engine on different base domains share session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cross-domain

I have a Rails app hosted on domain.com and an engine mounted on a different domain using this *routes* configuration:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Some::Engine => '/', as: 'some', constraints: { domain: 'other_domain.com' }
end
```

Is there any way, no matter how *hacky*, to have access to the same session on both domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your number one issue is that sessions are based on cookies and your browser won't send the cookies set by domain.com when making requests to otherdomain.com.

If you switch to a session store where the session cookie just identifies a row in some data store (eg memcached, redis etc) then you just need to share this session id.

I've not done it myself, but I have seen the following implemented.

1. User goes to example.com, with no cookies, they are redirected to master-domain.com
2. Master-domain.com sets a session cookie (eg with value abc-123) and redirects to example.com/?session_id=abc-123
3. example.com sets a session cookie with the same value (to avoid steps 1&2 on future requests) and stores session data against abc-123 in some data store
4. Later on, the user goes to other-domain.com, with no cookies. As in 1 they are redirected.
5. Master-domain reads its existing session cookie (with value abc-123) and redirects to other-domain.com/?session_id=abc-123
6. Other-domain.com repeats the steps from 3.

Now all of your domains are storing their session data with the same session id in the same data store: you're sharing sessions

I'd be inclined to say that if you really need to share session information (as opposed to, for example, just identity) then you're probably creating problems for yourself, but you did say you were open to anything.